# How to structure UML for more than 100 entities?

Tags: java, uml

I am designing a UML for my JAVA program class. It has 50+ attributes and 50+ properties. I have to include the UML in my report in word document. Is there any problem if the diagram gets split into multiple pages?

20+ properties have getters and setters, so it is necessary to include them?

And there are few other classes with which I have to show the relationship, the relationship diagram will be on another page, so on relationship UML do I have to list all the attributes again ? or I can just include the class name in the rectangle?

Comment: Just read the last sentence from @ister's answer! This is not a class, it's a design accident.

Comment: @ThomasKilian This class I am working on implements Swing components for a registration form, so the labels and text field declarations are mandatory. If this is a design accident, please guide me how should I ride safely on this path? Should I define a hashmap and store all the attributes on it? Because I donot see a logical reason to divide it into multiple classes as all the components are inter-related.

Comment: I don't know that Swing stuff (only by name and a rough idea), but if I'm right the attributes represent form fields. There are probably reasons for having such forms, but each time I see them I'm running as fast as I can. Else read the rest of @ister's post. Just add those attributes/operations to the diagram which are needed and leave the rest away.

Answer (score 2):

If your diagram contains only one class, what's the point of it. Maybe it's better to put just a textual class description?

On the other hand a single diagram spread across few pages isn't really readable anymore.

UML specification explicitly says that you place on your diagram only what is needed and useful in a specific context. You may put just a class name on other diagrams and that's fine.

Other option is to depict your class with properties and operations important from the perspective of specific interactions. You can show that the list is incomplete by placing an ellipsis after the last feature in each section.

If I had a case like you I would **very carefully** examine my design looking for flaws in it. A class with that many features can hardly ever be justified.

Comment: There are few others classes in the diagram. Mentioned class (having many attributes and methods) is for GUI. I have methods like clearing the form , accessors for all the form fields, methods to update some form fields based on user actions and much more. So my query is , should I split this into more classes? As you stated that a class with this many features can hardly be justified, does that mean in every situation (big system architectures) we should always divide the features into multiple classes even  if they are related to one parent feature (like Registration form GUI in my case) ?